# Parse json results in vbnet

Tags: json, vb.net, parsing

how I can parse following code retrieved in a textbox:

> {
>        "items": [
>         {
>          "snippet": {
>           "channelId": "UCcTbyoZjhqoCn4yVawpMFDA",
>           "title": "Forever - Stratovarius",
>           "categoryId": "10"
>          },
>          "statistics": {
>           "viewCount": "6180411",
>           "likeCount": "19060",
>           "dislikeCount": "342",
>           "favoriteCount": "0",
>           "commentCount": "3025"
>          }
>         }
>        ]
>       }

My code for get value title and likeCount:

```
     Dim url As String = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=8BvV9arABLs&key=KEYAPI&fields=items(id,snippet(channelId,title,categoryId),statistics)&part=snippet,statistics"
            Dim json As String = New WebClient().DownloadString(url)
            Dim root As JToken = JToken.Parse(json)
            Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

            For Each item As JToken In root("items")
            textbox1.text=sb.AppendLine(item.SelectToken("title") & sb.AppendLine(item.SelectToken("likeCount"))
            Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's better to format marked up data like JSON before you post it.

Like this:

```
{
    "items" : [{
            "snippet" : {
                "channelId" : "UCcTbyoZjhqoCn4yVawpMFDA",
                "title" : "Forever - Stratovarius",
                "categoryId" : "10"
            },
            "statistics" : {
                "viewCount" : "6180411",
                "likeCount" : "19060",
                "dislikeCount" : "342",
                "favoriteCount" : "0",
                "commentCount" : "3025"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As @rufanov said there are a lof of packages for JSON serialization.

As for me, I use Newtonsoft JSON. I use it in C# and will write examples in it, but I strongly believe it should be the same or similar on VB.NET.
Create classes for JSON objects. Pay attention: the members should be names as in JSON object.

```
public class JItemArray
{
    public JItem[] items;
}

public class JItem
{
    public JSnippet snippet;
    public JStatistics statistics;
}

public class JSnippet
{
    public string channelId;
    public string title;
    public string categoryId;
}

public class JStatistics
{
    public string viewCount;
    public string likeCount;
    public string dislikeCount;
    public string favoriteCount;
    public string commentCount;
}
```

Then, you will be able to do

```
JItemArray itemArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JItemArray>(yourJsonString);
```

It will throw JsonReaderException (with explanation in Message) if something fails.
Else, it will return a proper JItem .NET object with all necessary parsed data.

Here it is on NuGet website.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

But if you only need these two values it's pretty good practice to use JToken.

Answer (score 0):

There is [many NuGet packages for working with JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=json). Use one of them.